# Prevent ASP.NET Core application from using appsettings.json file

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings

I would like to tell to ASP.NET Core application that even if `appsettings.json` file is there - ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to write this as a comment but I'm still a newby here so I cannot ask questions.

I would like to understand what is the specific problem you are facing right now.
In general the usage or not of the appsettings file depends on your application.

For example, if you create a Web API using default .NET template, you can see that the appsettings file only has some configuration for logging, which you can even delete and nothing happens. You can run the application anyway and it works.

So, coming back to your question, it dependes on what your application is doing. If you have a specific library that needs to read configuration from this file, then you'll need to research how to change that default value.

If you are reading from that file, then you could set value in code instead. (this is obvious but since you didn't provide any more context I don't know what you are struggling with)